# What is a good resource for CA crop production data?

Tags: data

To construct maps depicting crop yield throughout California, are there statewide datasets, or would I need to add data by county?

Comment: I think this question is too narrowly focussed for this site, especially since it's a one-liner with no (visible) history of things that have been tried already to find an answer. That said, I think the answer would be to contact the California Department of Food & Agriculture and ask them. Failing responsiveness there, from their [statistics page pdf's](http://www.cdfa.ca.gov/statistics/) pull out the tables ordered by county and join to any standard county map set. The downloadable reports go back at least 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

[Farmland Mapping and Monitoring Program (FMMP)](http://www.conservation.ca.gov/DLRP/fmmp/Pages/Index.aspx)

FMMP has GIS data by county showing some different kinds of farmlands.